# Are there common circuit stability issues at low current levels and/or recommended minimum values?

Tags: mosfet, current, circuit-design, current-limiting, stability

I'm building a small semi-permanent solderable PCB circuit using a couple of mosfet inverters, plus some resistors for voltage division and pulling inputs/outputs high/low. The final location will be inside the cabin of an off-road vehicle in the general vicinity of a 20 kWh 48 V DC battery bank which shares a common ground with the vehicle's 12 V DC electrical system.

My 12V breadboard prototype functions well, and I'm keeping power consumption low, so my currents are often in the 300-500 uA range. The 48V version will get as low as 20 uA in some places.

Is there a lower limit on current where pcb parasitic capacitance, signal interference, or any other issues begin to play a role?

Do circuit designers often keep amperage at some nominal level to avoid these issues?

Do those values vary with environment, and if so, what would be good for automotive (assuming inside the vehicle, not in the engine compartment)?

Comment: You have to define a problem with results rather than a general vague question. EMI, ripple and step load all are unique to a design.

Comment: Avoiding PCB parasitic capacitance (and mutual inductance), signal interference and other issues is not something that one can say "Yes, stay below 10mA and all is well".   There are no fixed limits.   How susceptible your board will be depends on the design (As Tony says above), but it also CRITICALLY is dependent on your ability to do a proper PCB layout.   How & where you place your components, the loop areas you make with your traces, whether or not you use a multi-layer PCB, etc... are all very important factors to a successful project.  You can't fake your way through this either.

Comment: The fact you're near a battery bank won't matter if that's all it really is -- A steady DC battery bank.   It could be a horrendous issue if your battery bank also includes something that spews out high-frequency electromagnetic noise (like is there an inverter as part of this bank???)

Comment: Good info, thank you everyone. I knew this was vague but I see now it's too vague for any real value. I've built a prototype inverter circuit using IRF510N mosfets that works reliably on a breadboard, but indeed the final location for the PCB will be within 3.5 feet of an inverter. Should I be worried about interference even with that amount of physical spacing? I'll start reading up on PCB layout best practices. I've also been considering a single IC chip instead of a handful of IRF510Ns, maybe a CD40106B, but I wonder if it will be even more susceptible.

Comment: Moderators, please close this post. It was a poorly conceived question which made sense (to me) at the time, but now seems wildly vague.